# Induction question for $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: induction

If you want to do induction on a parameter $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. In the base case, you prove it for $a=0$. And then you suppose it is true for $n$ and prove it for $n+1$ and $n-1$? Is that correct?

Or you have to do induction for all $a\geq 0$ and then for all $a \leq 0$?

Comment: Are you saying that you need to prove some statement is true for *all* integers (not just non-negative ones)? In any case, how you use induction will depend on the problem you are trying to solve. What are you trying to prove?

Comment: Yes indeed for ALL integers. It's something about Fibonacci numbers (for all $a,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$): \begin{equation} F_{2mn+a} \equiv (-1)^{m(n+1)} F_a \mod L_n \end{equation}. And I want to do induction on $m$ for abritrary but fixed $n,a \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Your suggested method would certainly suffice. Prove that it is true when $m=0$. Let $r$ be an integer and suppose it is true for $m=r$, then prove that it is true when $m=r+1$ and $m=r-1$. Then the statement will be proven true for all integers by induction.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!